# Rearranging order of data frame rows based on a vector

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

I have the following data frame above and a vector x= 1, 156, 153, 3 , 185. My vector corresponds to node.id column showed in the picture and I would like to rearrange the rows of the data frame to match up with the order of my vector. So the order of the data frame rows should be the row with node.id= 1, then 156, 153,3,185. Hopefully, I explained this well enough.

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score -1):

We can use `match`

```
df1[match(df1$node.id, x),]
#  x     lon   lat node.id          name
#1  1 -122.41 37.70       1 San Francisco
#4 22 -117.16 32.71     156     San Diego
#3 21 -118.24 34.05     153   Los Angeles
#2  3 -115.14 36.16       3     Las Vegas
#5 26 -112.08 38.77     185     Richfield
```

#### data

```
df1 <-  structure(list(x = c(1, 3, 21, 22, 26), lon = c(-122.41, -115.14, 
-118.24, -117.16, -112.08), lat = c(37.7, 36.16, 34.05, 32.71, 
38.77), node.id = c(1, 3, 153, 156, 185), name = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Las Vegas", "Los Angeles", "Richfield", 
"San Diego", "San Francisco"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

x <- c(1, 156, 153, 3, 185)
```